# mysql, LOOP or WHILE can not be repeated.

Tags: mysql

I have tried two ways to repeat some code which are syntax correct, but seems like the loop (neither LOOP nor WHILE) can not be execute.

1 using WHILE:

```
SET @y =1;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS parm_y;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE parm_y()
BEGIN
WHILE @y != 62 DO //stop condition
INSERT INTO parm_y SELECT * FROM tempff WHERE op0=@y LIMIT 1;// repeating work 
SELECT addr INTO @y FROM tempff WHERE op0=@y LIMIT 1; // repeating work 
END WHILE;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

2 using LOOP:

```
SET @y =1;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS parm_y;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE parm_y()
BEGIN
y_loop: LOOP
INSERT INTO parm_y SELECT * FROM tempff WHERE op0=@y LIMIT 1; // repeating work 
SELECT addr INTO @y FROM tempff WHERE op0=@y LIMIT 1; //repeating work
IF @y = 62 THEN //stop condition
LEAVE y_loop;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I don't want to manually repeat those two lines. The syntax of both paragraph is correct. but neither one, enters in the loop.

Can anyone help me out? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are not in incrementing your counter `@y`. It should be like

```
SET @y =1; 

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS parm_y; DELIMITER // CREATE PROCEDURE parm_y() 

BEGIN 

WHILE @y < 62 DO //stop condition (changed from `!=` to `<`)

INSERT INTO parm_y SELECT * FROM tempff WHERE op0=@y LIMIT 1;// repeating work 

SELECT addr INTO @y FROM tempff WHERE op0=@y LIMIT 1; // repeating work 

SET @y = @y + 1; // Missing this part

END WHILE; 

END 

// DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: There are two lines need to be repeating. The first line is getting some value by @y. The second line is updating y. The stop condition is when y is a certain number. But the problem is that seems like the loop didn't be execute at all, even not enter into.

Comment: @Gwen, got it. let me look at it again. Will update my answer.

Comment: @Gwen, now I am confused; @y is a INT; Q's: in your INSERT INTO statement tablename and your PROC name are same `param_y` why? you said `select addr into @y from tempff` what is the value type of addr?